# javascript add script dynamicly end of page

Tags: javascript, insert, element

I want to add script after all scripts loaded. My code is:

```
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var get = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var count = get.length;

var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[count];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/57c6c47b2b03647ba16e0e84/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
```

And I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

The link is: https://www.alapar.az/

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an actual question?

Comment: Does document contain `<script>` elements before function is called?

Comment: of course! check this link: https://www.alapar.az

Comment: Your s0 variable isn't being assigned correctly before you're looking for its parent node. You may want to try wrapping this in another init() function and adding a script tag as the last element in your dom that calls init(); that way theoretically all your other script tags will be in place before you try to get the length of them. I can't check your code but I bet if you console.log(count) right after your var count = get.length your count will return as 0 or undefined.

Comment: can someone put here code? I couldn't understand. I have poor english

Comment: @AyxanƏmiraslanlı Substitute `[count -1]` for `[count]`, see Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute

```
s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[count -1] // note `-1`
```

for

```
s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[count]
```